# Отладка копии приложения в Visual Studio 2017

Tags: отладка, visual-studio-2017

Собственно есть приложение, которое компилируется на платформе убунту, и для удобства отладки было настроено на дебаг в Visual Studio.

В процессе исполнения это приложение вызывает само себя, и теперь мне нужно отлаживать 2 копии. Однако дебагер по умолчанию наблюдает только за оригиналом.

Использовать присоединение по понятным причинам не удается. Вопрос - есть ли возможность наблюдения за уже исполняемым приложением? Или же его можно перехватить до начала исполнения?

**Visual Studio 2017 Community**

Comment: Использовать присоединение по понятным причинам не удается. - это почему?

Comment: @Zergatul, потому что процесс уже запущен и интерпретатор просто не понимает в каком месте выполнения сейчас находится программа.

Comment: Все он понимает, зачем тогда вообще нужен "Attach to process". Важно только, что бы были нужные pdb файлы.

Comment: В данном случае, когда я пытаюсь присоединить уже работающий процесс, происходит ровным счетом ничего.

Comment: Вы выставили брейкпоинты? Они подсвечиваются как активные?

Comment: Да ставил. Как они должны быть подсвечены? Обычные брейкпоинты. У меня вся программа в них.

Comment: После подключения дебагера к процессу, брейкпоинты могут выглядеть как обычные (значит pdb подгружена), или как перечеркнутые (pdb не погружен или dll не подгружена в процесс) то есть они не сработают. В общем я не сильно понимаю, что там у вас происходит.

Comment: Они выглядят как обычные. После присоединения ко второму процессу не возникает ни ошибок, ни предупреждений. Просто студия продолжает отладку первого процесса.

Comment: То есть вы запускаете приложения со студии, и потом пытаетесь присоединится ко второму процессу?

Comment: Именно так. Запускаю приложение из VS, и в процессе отладки моей программы вызывается копия моей программы. Которую, в свою очередь, мне и нужно присоединить для отладки.

Comment: Запускайте другую студию, и из нее делайте attach, или же запускайте первую копию без студии (с exe файла), и делайте attach ко второй копии.

Comment: Я пробовал так уже. Все-равно из-за того что процесс уже был запущен, отладка не происходила.